# Why can't I use Font Awesome Icons within my div tag?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I've been trying to use Font Awesome icons within a card I made. Unfortunately, they simply do not appear anywhere within the div of my card. I'm thinking it has something to do with this the `.card` class `:before` selector considering it works without it.

Any idea how I can have icons in my card without altering the design?

```
.card :before {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.16);
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: normal;
  left: 50%;
  line-height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  width: 60px;
  color: #3498db;
  content: "AA";
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/bubblesphere/pen/GqXLZO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sayed Rafeeq said. You could use the [code](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) of the user icon instead of the `fa-user` class, which is `&#xf007;`

Example: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/orlandothoeny/pen/xOyVNX)

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. Any explanation why the conflict is happening?

Comment: I can't explain this to myself either

Answer (score 1):

You need to use icon Unicode for that. 

Check this [link](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) and css code:

```
.card:before {
   content: '\f105';
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm not looking to add an icon to the circle at the top. I want to use icons throughout the div itself. For example, in the codepen, where you see the label _There should be an icon before this label_, an icon should appear before

Answer (score 0):

Please do minor changes remove space between before and class. and font-family and content property.

```
.card:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.16);
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: normal;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    width: 60px;
    color: #3498db;
    content:"\f033"
    font-family: 'FontAwesome;
}
```